# loading module variables in interactive mode

Tags: python, interactive

Whenever I load a module while running python interactively I usually end up doing

```
some_variable = module.module_variable
```

To get a shorter variable name.

Is there a way to do this variable loading from the module to the interactive scope. so I don't have to repeat it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems to be what I was after. You just need to set the variable on the main namespace.

```
import __main__
__main__.some_variable = module.module_variable
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
from module import function as func
```

Comment: If you use that in the module, then you still have to use the module name in the shell to get the variable.